# When we sum column value in power bi table, if value is null or blank then how to show it as 0 in power?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

In my Power BI Dashboard table after creating dashboard if some row values are empty then how to make it as 0 instead of Null or Blank value

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If date field is missing then

```
Date =

VAR MCON = FORMAT(TODAY(),“dd/M/yyyy")

RETURN TF(
          SELECTEDVALUE('New Registration'[$1]) = BLANK(),
          MCON, 
          SELECTEDVALUE('New Registration'[$1])
         )
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After done R & D i found an solution, I have created measure and populated in Dashboard page instead of directly assigning the column value. The measure which i created is

```
Expenses Value =
IF (
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Expenses[Amount] ) ) = BLANK (),
    0,
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Expenses[Amount] ) )
)
```

[image]